# Поиск точного совпадения по множеству строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Всех приветствую, возникла проблема

в базе есть поле примерно с таким содержимым(это поле называется допустим value, в примере одно поле)

```
2222
2223
2224
22
2
```

Необходимо найти запись в котором есть запись например 22, исходя из этого понимаем что поиск LIKE '' или LIKE '%...%' не подходит, нужно точное совпадения строки, 2222 не подходит, подходит конкретно 22

Более менее рабочий вариант

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `value` RLIKE '[[:<:]]22[[:>:]]'
```

Comment: а почему не подходит like ?  вы же там можете спокойно указать переводы кареток. А вообще надо бы таблицу нормализовать, вынести множественное поле в виде отдельной таблицы, что бы было по одному значению на строку.

Comment: @Mike если like то потому что не будет точного совпадения, если like %% то будет находить лишние записи

Comment: не будет, если переводы кареток укажите

Comment: лучше бы конечно список через запятую делали, а не отдельными строками и искали бы стандартной функцией find_in_set

Comment: @Mike можно поподробней о "каретках" ?

Comment: Так Akina уже ответил. Если у вас в поле как бы несколько строк, то это лишь значит что между значениями у вас стоят переводы кареток, символы с кодом 10. которые можно указывать в любом месте запроса как `\n`. Они отличаются от тех же запятых только тем, что их не видно как обычные символы, потому что они обеспечивают переход на следующую строку. Правда в зависимости от того из какого источника получены значения переводы кареток могут быть разными, в windows это `\r\n`, в unix `\n`, в Mac OS `\r`

Answer (score 1):

Если речь не идёт об эффективности, то можно дофига чего нагородить.

Вариант 1:

```
WHERE CONCAT('\n', value, '\n') LIKE '%\n22\n%'
```

Вариант 2:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('22', REPLACE(value, '\n', ','))
```

Вариант 3:

```
WHERE value RLIKE '[[=\n=]]22[[=\n]]'
```

Можно ещё много чего понапридумывать... но лучше всё-таки данные нормализовать.

Comment: 3 вариант возвращает ошибку #1139 - Получена ошибка 'brackets ([ ]) not balanced' от регулярного выражения

Comment: @MAXGRIM У меня нормально работает... я даже не знаю, кого обвинить в том, что не указана версия сервера.

Comment: я не думал что версия сервера важна, версия - 5.7.16-10log

Comment: запустилось так WHERE value RLIKE '[[=\n=]]22[[=\n=]]', но вернуло пустой результат

Comment: ни один с вариантов не работает на чуть сложных задачах

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что запись твоего вида это не вся таблица, а конкретно одно поле одной записи из нее, то вроде так можно) (чур не смеяться)

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `value` RLIKE '(^22\\s)'
OR `value` RLIKE '(\\s22$)'
OR `value` RLIKE '(\\s22\\s)'
OR `value` RLIKE '(^22$)'
```

Comment: А если это все записи этого поля из всей таблицы, то так:

SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `value` LIKE '22'